# Skype/Messenger Prompts

Tags: c#, wpf

I was wondering if anyone could point me in any documentations about Prompt messages like how you would get when someone messages you on skype, or the old school messengers. I tried googles but nothing has come up within the search criteria I've inputted. Any help would definitely be appreciated. I am trying to create an informative prompt or sometimes error window. But that's not as direct. Skype prompts appear and just disappear after a short while which is my aim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure if this is what you are looking for, but take a look at :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon